# adding comma separator for numbers,every third digit while typing

Tags: ios, xcode

i'm trying to add a comma separator for every third digit that user enters in textfield right away while typing for iOS app using swift 4.0 and Xcode 9.
so far i've added these lines of code to my viewdidload method:

```
     self.mainTextField.delegate = self

  self.mainTextField(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

ive also added this function to my view controller:

```
func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == self.mainTextField {

            // Some locales use different punctuations.
            var textFormatted = textField.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
            textFormatted = textFormatted?.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "")

            let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
            if let text = textFormatted, let textAsInt = Int(text) {
                textField.text = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: textAsInt))
            }
        }
    }
```

but i keep receiving this error from Xcode :
Cannot call value of non-function type 'UITextField'
on this line:

self.mainTextField(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)

Comment: `self.mainTextField(self, ...` => `self.mainTextField.addTarget(self, ...` ?

Comment: Awesome solution - Ive been looking for this solution for days. Thank you. One question though - I also want to be able to put a dot(.) as decimal.

Comment: @SiphoKoza you can define the numberFormatter yourself     numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        numberFormatter.groupingSeparator = "."
        numberFormatter.groupingSize = 3
        numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
        numberFormatter.decimalSeparator = "."

Comment: @mdehghani Thank you. Its working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the method name `addTarget`. Instead of

```
self.mainTextField(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

use

```
self.mainTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
```